# Nesting a Matrix variable type inside textarea variable (Low Variables)

Tags: add-on, matrix, low-variables

I've got a variable set up as a 2-col Matrix for easy editing of days/hours (for being open). I'm wanting to nest this in another variable, that contains the mark-up for this snippet (so-to-speak). I have early parse enabled the Matrix var type but within the `{lv_footer}`, it just returns the code as a string from the "nested" var `{lv_hours}`. Anyway I can have that parse before the `{lv_footer}` is parsed?

Here is code in the lv_footer (saved as file):

```
<div class="hours">
    <h3>Hours:</h3>
    <dl class="hours">
    {exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_hours"}
        <dt>{day}</dt>
        <dd>{hours}</dd>
    {/exp:low_variables:pair}
    </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the way Low Variables parses nested variables. You may need to add both of these variables to the same group and in the right order for them to parse correctly: `{lv_footer}` should be above `{lv_hours}` in the same group

> #### Nesting
>
> [cue Inception music] So, there are three stages at which a Low
> Variable can be parsed:
>
> 1. As early parsed global variables using the variable syntax (stage 1)
> 2. As tags, single or pair, using the tag syntax (stage 5)
> 3. As late parsed global variables (the default) using the variable syntax (stage 9).
>
> Looking at these stages, you can always nest variables upwards: 2 in
> 1, 3 in 1, and 3 in 2. As noted before, you can also nest 1 in 1, but
> only if they are in the same group and in the right order.
> Theoretically, you can nest 2 in 2, but that might cause your brain to
> melt. Nesting 3 in 3 won’t necessarily break things, but it can lead
> to unexpected results. Nesting 1 in 2, 1 in 3, or 2 in 3 will never
> work.

[More on the parse order](http://gotolow.com/blog/parse-order-and-low-variables)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Nesting quote Siebird posted, you'll also need to know what the different stages (1, 5 and 9) mean.

**Stage 1** is for **early parsed global variables**: Low Variables with early parsing *enabled* and in *variable* syntax: `{lv_my_variable}`

**Stage 5** is for **tags**: Low Variables using the *tag* syntax: `{exp:low_variables:single var="lv_my_variable"}`
*Note: Early Parsing has no effect when using the tag syntax!*

**Stage 9** is for **late parsed global variables**: Low Variables with early parsing *disabled* and in *variable* syntax: `{lv_my_variable}`

This means, for your example, that you have 2 vars that are nested. One of them, `lv_hours`, needs the *tag* syntax, and therefore is parsed at *stage 5*. So if you want to nest it inside `lv_footer`, you need to parse that one in *stage 1*: make sure you use *variable* syntax and that early parsing is *enabled*.

Comment: Is it possible to use variable syntax with a Matrix variable type? I tried essentially replacing the _tag_ syntax and just use the var name (ie. `{lv_hours}{/lv_hours}`) without success. How can I get that var to parse in stage 1?

And do they need to be in the same group?

(thanks for the help - first time using Low Variables)

Comment: No, global variables do not support the variable pair syntax. Matrix vars can only be parsed using the tag syntax. But as long as the `lv_footer` is parsed early, and it contains the matrix var tag, it should work.